# How to calculate average time interval between orders

Tags: mysql

Suppose `order` table: `user_id, order_id, created (timestamp)`, ...

How to calculate average time interval between consequent orders of one user? (How often users create orders?)

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when count(order_id) = 0
       then -1
       else (max(created) - min(created)) / count(order_id)
       end as avg_order_time
from `order`
where user_id = 123
```

Comment: . . I think you mean `max() - min()`.

Comment: And it should also be `count(order_id) - 1`, probably with a conditional to be sure there is more than one order.

Comment: `SELECT AVG(days / (ordrs-1)) FROM (
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as ordrs, DATEDIFF(MAX(created), MIN(created)) AS days FROM `order`
WHERE status_id=3
GROUP BY user_id
) s
WHERE ordrs > 1`